# Writing a system of Linear Equations

Tags: alignat

I found this program and I was wondering how can I add on a left brace as in the `systeme` package or in the `cases` environment? Also is it possible to left align the right-hand side of the equal sign ?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{4}
   2x & {}+{} &  y & {}+{} & 3z & {}={} & 10 \\
    x & {}+{} &  y & {}+{} &  z & {}={} &  6 \\
    x & {}+{} & 3y & {}+{} & 2z & {}={} & 13
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What's the problem in using `\systeme`?

Comment: @egreg , I will be using the tikzmark package and not sure if it will work. I wanted some other options incase it does not. I will try this later today

Comment: In Italian we say something like “bandaging one's head before it gets hurt”.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `\begin{alignat*}{4}[left = \empheqlbrace]` solution which you employ in your own answer requires hand-editing "`& 6`" to "`& 6\phantom{0}`" in order to generate the appearance of left-alignment in the final column.

If that's too tedious and/or error-prone, do also consider the `\systeme`- and `array`-based solutions shown below.

Note that the three solutions produce the *exact same output*. In the end, then, your decision should be based mainly on the convenience of the input process. In my opinion, the input convenience of the `systeme` method is hard to beat. For sheer flexibility, though, the `array`-based method must be tops; however, its input overhead does exceed that of the `systeme` approach (and is roughly on par with the `empheq` appoach).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}          % for Solution 1
\usepackage[overload]{empheq} % for Solution 2
\usepackage{systeme}          % for Solution 3
\usepackage{array}            % for Solution 4
\newcolumntype{C}{>{{}}c<{{}}} 

\begin{document}
%% Solution 1: use 'alignat*'
\begin{alignat*}{4}
   2x & {}+{} &  y & {}+{} & 3z & {}={} & 10 \\
    x & {}+{} &  y & {}+{} &  z & {}={} &  6 \\
    x & {}+{} & 3y & {}+{} & 2z & {}={} & 13
\end{alignat*}

%% Solution 2: use 'empheq' machinery and a '\phantom' directive
\begin{alignat*}{4}[left = \empheqlbrace]
   2x & {}+{} &  y & {}+{} & 3z & {}={} & 10 \\
    x & {}+{} &  y & {}+{} &  z & {}={} &  6\phantom{0} \\ % <-- note "\phantom{0}"
    x & {}+{} & 3y & {}+{} & 2z & {}={} & 13
\end{alignat*}

%% Solution 3: use 'systeme' machinery
\[
\systeme{2x+y+3z=10, x+y+z=6, x+3y+2z=13}
\]

%% Solution 4: use the basic 'array' machinery
\[
\setlength\arraycolsep{0pt}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.25}
\left\{
\begin{array}{*{3}{rC}l}
   2x & + &  y & + & 3z & = & 10 \\
    x & + &  y & + &  z & = &  6 \\
    x & + & 3y & + & 2z & = & 13
\end{array}
\right.
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Last night I by accident found another solution to your solution #2; namely place a double ampersand, &&, in the  last ampersand column so it will be right-adjusted and no column space

Comment: I am thinking of using the  tikzmark package with one of these solutions. Not sure if systeme will allow this though.

Comment: @MathScholar - I'm afraid I'm not familiar with TikZ and `tikzmark`.

Answer (score 11):

You're overcomplicating things:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\left\{
\begin{alignedat}{3}
% R & L   &  R & L   &  R & L 
 2x & +{} &  y & +{} & 3z & = 10 \\
  x & +{} &  y & +{} &  z & = 6 \\
  x & +{} & 3y & +{} & 2z & = 13
\end{alignedat}
\right.
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course one might also use `systeme`. The alignment in the codes below is not necessary, it's used just to ease the reading of the code itself.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,systeme}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\systeme{
 2x +  y + 3z = 10,
  x +  y +  z = 6,
  x + 3y + 2z = 13
}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If one adds `\sysalign{r,r}` to the document preamble, the output would be

[image]

A different example motivated by [Displaying linear equation (variable under variable)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/594253/4427)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,systeme}

\sysalign{r,r}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\systeme{
 3x_1 + 2x_2 -  x_3 +  x_4 = -1,
 2x_1        -  x_3 + 2x_4 = 0,
 3x_1 +  x_2 + 2x_3 + 5x_4 = 2
}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Use `\usepackage[overload]{empheq}` in the preamble

Adding
    `\begin{alignat*}{4}[left = \empheqlbrace]` will get the left brace.

[image]

I still need to align the right-hand side of the equation to the left. Not sure if this idea is more versatile than the `systeme` package? Can anyone advise?

Comment: Are you answer your own question? and then have another question? If that is the case then edit your question and wait for someone to assist you.

Comment: I answered half of it!

Comment: Using `\begin{equation*}\left\{\begin{alignedat}{4}<same code>\end{alignedat}\right.\end{equation*}` would do without the need of `empheq`.

Answer (score 3):

Adding another ampersand to the last column right-adjusts the column after the equal sign:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[overload]{empheq} 

\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{4}[left = \empheqlbrace]
   2x & {}+{} &  y & {}+{} & 3z & {}={} && 10 \\
    x & {}+{} &  y & {}+{} &  z & {}={} && 6  \\
    x & {}+{} & 3y & {}+{} & 2z & {}={} && 13
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please extend your code snippet to an MWE. Now is not possible to reproduce showed result.

Comment: @Zarko, sorry about that I will fix!