# Displaying linear equation (variable under variable)

Tags: spacing, equations, horizontal-alignment

I'm quite new to Latex and I would like to display an linear equation in this kind of format:

[image]

So that every variable has its own column.
What methods do exist?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/508349/134144 might serve as a place to start from.

Comment: I have updated my answer to the linked duplicate to show a different method.

Comment: Now I used the first solution showed in the post. Is it also possible to change the amount of spacing?